# React Router trigger re-load / re-mount component on redirecting to same page with different slug

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lifecycle, react-router-dom

I have a demo application that uses **React (v.16.8.6)** and **HashRouter** (a requirement to **use hash router**). My app simply fetches some weather data and displays the relevant components for weather in some cities.

The problem is that there is a search feature in index page and also similar feature on search page. When search term is given app redirects to `#/search/{term}` route. Everything is working as expected however when I am already on search page and trigger new search I redirect to same search page with different `{term}` slug (needed in order to update browser current url including hash).

As a result page is NOT reloaded and component is NOT remounted so lifecycle hooks (especially `componentDidMount` where the setup is made) are not triggered.

I made a workaround to simulate component re-load, but it is sort of a hack (eg manipulating state directly and settting timeout see below relevant code).

Is there a better way of achieving redirect to same page (and changing browser url including hash) while component is reloaded/remounted correctly?

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { HashRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

import HomePage from './home';
import SearchPage from './search';
import WeatherPage from './weather';

import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
    <HashRouter basename="/" hashType="slash">
    <Switch>
        <Route exact path={'/'} component={HomePage}></Route>
        <Route path={'/weather/:woeid'} component={WeatherPage}></Route>
        <Route path={'/search/:term'} component={SearchPage}></Route>
    </Switch>
    </HashRouter>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**SearchPage.js component**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import Weather from '../components/Weather';

function fetchData( term ) {
    return fetch('{api_url_here}?keyword='+term)
    .then(response => response.json());
}

class SearchPage extends Component {
  constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.state = {
          loading: true,
          text: this.props.match.params.term,
          redirect: false,
          data: null
      };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetchData(this.props.match.params.term).then(jsonResponse => {
        this.setState({
            loading: false,
            data: jsonResponse
        });
    });
  }

  handleOnClick = () => {
    this.setState({redirect: true});
  }

  handleInput = (evt) => {
    this.setState({text: evt.target.value});
  }

  render() {
    // any way to avoid this workaround while redirecting to same page?
    // [from here]
     if (this.state.redirect) {
        this.state.redirect = false;
        this.state.text = this.state.text.toLowerCase();
        this.state.data = null;
        this.state.loading = true;
        // simulate componentDidMount, since it os not re-called on same page
        setTimeout(()=>(fetchData(this.state.text).then(jsonResponse => {
            this.setState({
                loading: false,
                data: jsonResponse
            });
        })), 40);
        // redirect and update url
        return <Redirect to={"/search/"+this.state.text} />;
       // [to here]
  }
    return (
      <div>
      <h1>Search Page</h1>
      <div>
      <input type="text" placeholder="search.." value={this.state.text} onChange={this.handleInput} />
      <button type="button" onClick={this.handleOnClick}>Search!</button>
      </div>
      {this.state.loading ? 'Loading..' : (this.state.data && this.state.data.length ? this.state.data.map(res => (<Weather woeid={res.woeid} city={res.title} />)) : 'No results found!')}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default SearchPage;
```

Solution based on **Redirect** (which will re-load / re-mount component) ([Tholle's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55686729/3591273))

change **App** to following:

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
    <HashRouter basename="/" hashType="slash">
    <Switch>
        <Route exact path={'/'} component={HomePage}></Route>
        <Route path={'/weather/:woeid'} component={WeatherPage}></Route>
        <Route path={'/search/:term'} render={props => <SearchPage key={props.match.params.term.toLowerCase()} {...props} />}></Route>
    </Switch>
    </HashRouter>
    );
  }
}
```

change **SearchPage** to following:

```
class SearchPage extends Component {
  constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.state = {
          loading: true,
          text: this.props.match.params.term,
          redirect: false,
          data: null
      };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetchData(this.props.match.params.term).then(jsonResponse => {
        this.setState({
            loading: false,
            data: jsonResponse
        });
    });
  }

  handleOnClick = () => {
    this.setState({redirect: true});
  }

  handleInput = (evt) => {
    this.setState({text: evt.target.value});
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.redirect) {
        // redirect and update url
        return <Redirect to={"/search/"+this.state.text.toLowerCase()} />;
  }
    return (
      <div>
      <h1>Search Page</h1>
      <div>
      <input type="text" placeholder="search.." value={this.state.text} onChange={this.handleInput} />
      <button type="button" onClick={this.handleOnClick}>Search!</button>
      </div>
      {this.state.loading ? 'Loading..' : (this.state.data && this.state.data.length ? this.state.data.map(res => (<Weather woeid={res.woeid} city={res.title} />)) : 'No results found!')}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of going about it is to add a `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle hook to the `SearchPage` component and check if the `term` parameter changes and do the search again.

If you want to remount the component when the `term` parameter changes instead, you can use the `key` prop to unmount the previous component and mount a new one when the `key` changes.

```
<Route
  path={"/search/:term"}
  render={props => <SearchPage key={props.match.params.term} {...props} />}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Link` from `react-router-dom` instead of the `<button>` to change the route instead of just redirecting. Then in the onClick of the `<Link>` component call the `fetchData` and set the state accordingly.

```
<Link className="btn" to={"/search/"+this.state.text} onClick={this.handleOnClick}>Search!</Link>
```

Then in the `handleOnClick` function

```
handleOnClick() {
   this.setState({
      loading: true
   });
   fetchData(this.state.text).then(jsonResponse => {
     this.setState({
        loading: false,
        data: jsonResponse
     });
   });
}
```

Comment: Sorry! My bad. Use `this.state.text` instead of `props.match.params.term` in the `handleOnClick` as the onclick will trigger before changing the route

Comment: tried to us that (removed redirect and state.redirect and handleOnClick as it is not needed) but I got error `this.state.text is undefined`. Let me try again in  a couple of minutes

Comment: Try using `handleOnClick` binding with `this`. Like `<Link className="btn" to={"/search/"+this.state.text} onClick={this.handleOnClick.bind(this)}>Search!</Link>`

Comment: unfortunately search page will not reload update when using link (browser url changes) but component is NOT updated (still shows previous results). Note that I have removed the `onHandleClick` from `Link` as it is not needed (no redirect is made) and removed all `if ( this.state.redirect ) ..` code from `render` method. If you can post a full example based on my inoput where I can make it work I can upvote

Comment: The Link component will just change the browser URL. As you are already in the search page the SearchPage component will not remount. So you have to use the handlOnClick function to fetch the new data using the new input. Glad that you've already found an answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191844/discussion-between-sazedul-islam-sazid-and-nikos-m).

Comment: yes I would like for component to trigger reload/remount to avoid having this extra logic and workaround in render method (only have the `componentDidMount` logic). I see your approach now, take an upvote